# How to apply keypress and mousedown event on dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am working in an application where i have three textboxes dynamically polulated,one is for input value 2nd one  is for a time and 3 rd one is also for a time both 2nd and 3 rd boxes have timepicker api in it.So now what i need i will type something in the textbox and also select time from those two timepicker boxes and values will be appending on the respective textboxes on top of them.Like i am giving a fiddle where i have implemented the situation i have reached so far,This is it [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/info2jeet/6tpmyro1/1)

So i will write something on textbox1 and that will be that will be showing on textbox on top of it and also i will select a time from 2 nd box and 3 rd box and that will be on the 2 nd and 3 box on top of that.I am trying to use keypress and mousedown but that is not working on dynamic population of the textboxes like i tried using

```
$('#TextBoxContainer').on('keypress', 'input', function () {

});
```

But this is not giving the value of the textboxes .Somebody please help

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/4a0pcx5j/1/) what you are looking for? just updated your fiddle .

Comment: @JSantosh not exactly because when i am creating the next row using add then the value on the 1st box  which is on the top is replacing its previous value,i want all the values be there and also my timepicker are not working

Comment: time picker is not working because you didnt add `time` class to second text box . and how do want to append all values i mean seperate with comma or period etc ?

Comment: @JSantosh can you see it once ??

Comment: check my answer @lucifer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

**Note** : I used `comma` to separate the values from different text boxes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/08uq09cL/1/)

HTML

```
<input id="text1" type="text" value="" />
<input id="text2" type="text" value="" />
<input id="text3" type="text" value="" />
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);    
        $(".time").timepicker();
        $('.txt1,.txt2,.txt3').change(function () {
            UpdateData()
     });
});
$("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
    var valuesarr = new Array();
    var phonearr = new Array();
    var phonearr1 = new Array();
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        valuesarr.push($(this).val());
        $('#DynamicTextBox').val(valuesarr);
    });
    $("input[name=phoneNum]").each(function () {
        phonearr.push($(this).val());
        $('#phoneNum').val(phonearr);
    });

    $("input[name=phoneNum1]").each(function () {
        phonearr1.push($(this).val());
        $('#phoneNum1').val(phonearr1);
    });

    alert(valuesarr);
    alert(phonearr);
    alert(phonearr1);
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});

});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
return '<input class="txt1" name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;<input class="txt2 time" id="myPicker" class="time" type="text" />&nbsp;<input name = "phoneNum1" id="phoneNum1" class="time txt3"  type="text" /><input  type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />';
}

function UpdateData() {
    var text1 = ''
    $('#TextBoxContainer').find('.txt1').each(function (index, Obj) {
        if ($(Obj).val()) text1 += $(Obj).val() + ','
    })

    $('#text1').val(text1)
    var text2 = ''
    $('#TextBoxContainer').find('.txt2').each(function (index, Obj) {
        if ($(Obj).val()) text2 += $(Obj).val() + ','
    })
    $('#text2').val(text2)
    var text3 = ''
    $('#TextBoxContainer').find('.txt3').each(function (index, Obj) {
        if ($(Obj).val()) text3 += $(Obj).val() + ','
    })
    $('#text3').val(text3)
}
```

Comment: @lucifer , what i noticed here is in the timepicker plugin you used, is accepting characters, better try other plugins to force user to enter(or select ) time

Comment: @J Santosh thanks for your suggestion , i want to add one more specification on click of remove the latest element which is added to the textbox will be removed .How can it be done??

Comment: @J Santosh thanks for reply but this is not working properly,like it is deleting the data from the first box only and i want this functionality on the remove button like i will click on the remove button and the data will be deleted from the upperboxes.

Comment: @J Santosh your example works fine for me but i want that first 3 textboxes will be shown by default and then adding will bring the dynamic textboxes .. can you edit please ??

Comment: @lucifer I didn't get you. can you elaborate

Comment: now the example in the fiddle having one add button and three textboxes which holds the data by comma separated values i want by default three  boxs which was coming by clicking the add button will be there and then i will add more textboxes and so on and those three textboxes will have same function which dynamic textboxs shows

Comment: @J Santosh please update the fiddle it will be very helpful

Comment: [Lets continue discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91677/discussion-betweeen-ssantosh-and-lucifer)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you don't need processing `keypress` and `mousedown` events.

You just need to process `onsubmit` event of your `form`. Just read values from `textbox`, `DateTimeBox`, `DateTimeBox` and paste them to newly created `textbox2`, `DateTimeBox21`, `DateTimeBox22`.

Comment: i am using a form and i will submit that also ,so if what you r suggesting will  solve my purpose but then can you update my fiddle with that functionality??

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to create dynamicly 3 input boxes with the value of `text1` `text2` and `text3` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tpmyro1/2/) is the result.

And this is pretty much what i've changed:

```
...
$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
    var a = $("#text1");
    var b = $("#text2");
    var c = $("#text3");
    var div = $("div");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(a, b , c));
...
```

Obviously in `GetDynamicTextBox()` function i'm filling the InputBoxes with the expected values (from a, b and c).

In case you want to update `text1` `text2` and `text3` with the values of the generated input boxes [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4a0pcx5j/3/) would do it:

here is the relevant code i've changed on this one:

```
$('.txt1').bind('keyup',function(e){
    var code = e.which; 
    if(code==13)e.preventDefault();
    if(code==32||code==13||code==188||code==186){
      $('#text1').val($('#text1').val()+', '+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

For the above solution to work, you've got to press enter after changing each input box.

In case you preffer to not press enter [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4a0pcx5j/5/) you've got a solution which works when the generated input box loses the focus.

This is the relevant code:

```
   $('.txt1').bind('focusout',function(){  
          $('#text1').val($('#text1').val()+', '+$(this).val());
    });
```

You might want to check if the new value is the same that the old one or not in this one.

PS: I'm showing here the snippet of just the first inputbox since for the rest of them is pretty much the same. The complet solution is in the jsfiddle though.

Comment: no this is not what i want sir in your edit the first box is not showing its value to the top box

Comment: @lucifer the first dynamicly created textbox is filled with the content of `text1`, that is what i understand that you want. What is what you really are trying to achieve then?

Comment: but in your fiddle the 1 st textbox is not getting the value i am inputting into it,have you checked ???

Comment: Which is the first textbox for you? `DynamicTextBox` or `text1`? Because in my edit `DynamicTextBox` is getting the value of `text1` and that is what you are asking for as far as i can see.

Comment: I checked it again DynamicTextBox is not also getting value of text1

Comment: are you sure this is the url you are clicking? http://jsfiddle.net/6tpmyro1/2/ because it works. Close the one you've got and open this one: http://jsfiddle.net/6tpmyro1/2/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88246/discussion-between-vdevatman-and-lucifer).